# Using CSS root ems and scaling down font-size

Tags: ipad, css, fonts, autoscaling

I have converted a section of my site from using CSS ems to rems.

Generally this has worked out well for me across devices including the ipad. However, I have a bunch of portrait-specific styling and one of these is: font-size: 65%;

I know that when using ems my font scaling works, however where I have used rems the font size is unaffected in portrait mode.

Short of going through all my CSS and changing it back to em (which would be time-consuming), do I have any other options?

Why do rems not play well with font scaling?

I should add that the native scaling did not work with the design which led to the use of portrait-specific overrides. (The project has also been inherited).

Comment: Are you complaining that rems ignore your `font-size: 65%;` declaration?  If so, that's their whole point, unless of course that CSS is applied to the HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of rems is to ignore font size changes on elements other than the root (HTML) element.  If you want to make a font size change that affects the size of rems, then apply it to the HTML element.

Comment: OK, so essentially this means that I would be forced to use `em` instead of `rem` if I wanted to scale?

Comment: When using `rem`s, you can still scale the whole page together, by applying the font size to `html`.  If you're trying to scale just part of the page, then yes, you need `em`s.  (Or you could go with a CSS transform, I guess.)